# Is there a way to paint engine/suspension parts in Car Mechanic Simulator?

Tags: car-mechanic-simulator-2018

Just bought Car Mechanic Simulator on my Xbox. I have fully upgraded the garage and figured out how to paint the body and wheels, but there is no option to paint any engine/suspension parts. Was wondering if there was a place in the garage I was missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That would ruin them. Unless it's a deliberately annoying game I wouldn't expect it to be possible.

Comment: The graphics are that of a mobile game and the only effort you need is moving the controller. Its fun in some ways but lets just say it's worth it's price.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to paint suspension or engine parts in any of the Car Mechanic Simulator games. I do agree that this would be a good feature though!